# Best way to store data on server side for Java multilayer top down game

Tags: java, multiplayer, 2d-games

Me and some friends are making a top down shooter in Java and wanted to make it online we have set up a UDP socket connection which works fine but we aren't to sure about how to store data that we receive from the client.

at the moment we are using a number of hashmaps to store the data, for example we have three hashmaps for player tracking, game information (number of players etc) and bullets (bullet locations, who fired etc).

But I am sure that there must be a better more secure way of storing this data other than hashmaps but not to sure what.

*edit* thx- Philipp (Sorry it took so long for a half decent question)

My concern about using hashmaps to store this data is that there are quite a lot of data to be put into them and we are currently using a single row to store all data for a object for example a row in the player hashmap would have the player id as the key, with a string value to store anything else such as "hp,xloc,yloc". which we then split to use. Which I cant seem to think is the most efficient way to store and retrieve the data.

Sorry if this still doesn't make sense.

I suppose my real question is are there any alternatives that are more efficient or if the hashmap is the best way to go?

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly do you believe that your approach is inadequate? What bothers you with it?

Comment: IDK I just feel as if hashmaps are wrong in some way maybe its because its too simple and I'm being paranoid about it lol. if u guys think that the hashmap is okay then dismiss this question (it probably is my paranoia)

Comment: why do you think your approach is too simple? (By the way: this, and my previous questions were not rhetoric - I am trying to help you to better understand your problem. Otherwise you can't ask a meaningful question which will help you to solve it)

Comment: Okay I'll try to explain my reasoning. The game has three hashmaps as I mentioned above. I'll admit I dont know a whole lot about them but currently we use a single row in the map to store all the information for the player, bullet or game which we then split to get the values that we need for example the player map would be Player.put(id, "100,100"); then we would split the value from id and return it but having to split it each time seems a bit inefficient to me

Comment: aah, we are getting closer. You should edit your question and add your concerns about splitting the strings which carry your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out yourself, storing the data about each entity in the game in a string is not a good idea.

You have to parse the string whenever you need some information about it, and string parsing isn't very fast and can easily get pretty complicated when the data about each entity gets more complex.

A much better way to do this is to create a class for each entity type with a set of class variables and use this to store the data about each entity:

```
class Player {
    public: 
         int positionX;
         int positionY;
         int lifes;
         String name;
         //...
}
```

(by the way: an experienced object-oriented programmer would declare these variables as private and use getter and setter methods for changing them, but let's not go that far for now)

Your hash maps would then store instances of this class:

```
 HashMap<Integer, Player> players;
```

Setting these up is easy:

```
 Player p = new Player();
 p.positionX = 200;
 p.positionY = 400;
 p.lifes = 3;
 p.name = "Ford Prefect";
 players.put(42, p);
```

(By the way: An experienced OOP programmer would use a constructor)

You can set and get the variables of each player by accessing the hash map:

```
 players.get(42).positionX += 10; // move player 42 10 pixels to the right
```

Comment: I see what you're saying basically create a class and then use the hashmap to get to the dynamically made class of the player and update things as needed. this is great thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In-memory *is fine*. Unless you need to persist the data, *don't worry about it*.

However, "which we then split to use" is *not fine*. It's a micro-"optimization" that will actually be slower/less efficient: naught but pain and lost time lies down this route.

I don't know your particular setup, but consider this:

```
class Player {
   public Player (int playerId) {
      this.playerId = playerId;
   }

   // ID during game - not permanent; for link-back to Hash key
   public final int playerId;

   // Add methods and fields as appropriate
   String name;
   int health;
   // position, armour color, fairy dust, etc.
}

// How ids are "connected" to players:
//   playerId -> Player
Map<Integer,Player> players = new HashMap..;

// When a player "connects"
int playerId = getUniqueIdForGameInstance();
Player player = new Player(playerId); // setup other information as required
players.add(player.playerId, player);

// On attack ..
int attackerId = getAttackerFromClient();
int targetId = getTargetFromClient();

Player attacker = players.get(attackerId);
Player target = players.get(targetId);
target.getWumped(attacker.wumpStength());
```

The same can be applied for other entities in the game. Notice that the Map is used to be able to *find* a player given a particular ID, but an instance of the Player class holds information about the player.

Look at [ProtocolBuffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for serialization across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmaps are an ok solution - they're thread-safe, so assuming you don't have 10,000 users accessing your website at once, they should work for you.

However, at present all your data is stored in memory. This is a problem if the program terminates.

The simplest recommendation I can give it to write your HashMaps to a file. This is done in Java by adding the `Serializable` interface to your class declaration - however you do not need to do this for HashMap as it is already Serializeable. (You only have to do this for classes you have written that are stored in the HashMap.)

then just add the following to your main() method (to read from a file):

```
try {
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Game.sav");
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
  HashMap<K,V> loadedGame = (HashMap<K,V>) ois.readObject();
} catch (Exception e) {
       // Create new hash maps (no HashMap files found)
}
```

and this to a saveGame() method that can be called at your discretion

```
try {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Game.sav");
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
  o.writeObject(hashmapGameVariable);
  o.close();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace(); // something went wrong, you may not have write premissions
}
```